# Can I refinance a 2004 car?

Tags: refinance, auto-loan

I bought a 2004 Chevrolet Malibu one year ago I owe a little over 10000 . My interest rate is 20% . My boyfriend said he will cosign for me to refinance, is that possible?

Comment: What country. Please add the country tag.

Comment: The 2004 Chevy Malibu is worth roughly $5500 at the moment; see http://www.motortrend.com/cars/2004/chevrolet/malibu/pricing/

Comment: OK, I'll ask:  Why on earth did you pay that much for a 10 year old car?  Is this negative equity from a previous vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to.  Here is why you don't have the collateral.   You have a car that is probably not worth 10k.  Also you probably do not have a simple interest loan.  You have to look at your contract.  Make sure that there is not early payment fee.  Also look for the rule of 78's   [Explanation of Rule of 78's](http://www.bankrate.com/brm/news/auto/20010827a.asp)

I can't sugarcoat this chances are you were ripped off because you had bad credit putting you into an even deeper hole.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Sure. The question is where do you plan on going to get the money and how well can you shop around to find the best rate for the loan. Banks and credit unions would be one option but I'd be curious as to how well do you know the various routes you could take.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve a substitute for refinancing, but because of the "short" life of cars at least relative to housing, there are no true refinancings.

First, the entire loan will not be able to be refinanced.  The balance less approximately 80% of the value of the car will have to be repaid.  Cars depreciate by something like 20% per year, so $2,000 will have to be repaid.

Now, you should be able to get a loan if your boyfriend has good credit, but the interest rate will not drop too much further from the current loan's rate because of your presumably bad credit rating, assumed because of your current interest rate.

While this is doable, this is not a good strategy if you intend to have a long term relationship.  One of the worst corruptors of a relationship is money.  It will put a strain on your relationship and lower the odds of success.

The optimal strategy, if the monthly payments are too high, is to try to sell the car so to buy a cheaper car.  The difficulty here is that the bank will not allow this if balance of the loan exceeds the proceeds from the sale, so putting as much money towards paying the balance to allow a sale is best.

As a side note, please insure your car against occurrences such as theft and damage with a deductible low enough to justify the monthly payment.  It is a terrible position to have a loan, no car, and no collateral against the car.